TypeORM query a self referencing many to many relationship both ways
I have a table that has a many-to-many relationship to itself.
My relationship if defined such as:
 @ManyToMany((type) => TagEntity, { cascade: false })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'tags_tags_relation',
    joinColumn: { name: 'tag_id_1', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'tag_id_2', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  })
    relatedTo: TagEntity[];

The issue is the way the relationship is defined, I can only query the tags that are related to a given tags if the id of this tag is in the tag_id_1 column.
for example, given



tag_id_1
tag_id_2




HVAC
Plumber


HVAC
Roofing


Glazier
Plumber



const HVAC = AppDataSource.manager.findOne(TagEntity, {
          where: { name: 'HVAC' },
          relations: { relatedTo: true },
        }
// ==> HVAC.relatedTo will have 2 tag entities

const plumber = AppDataSource.manager.findOne(TagEntity, {
          where: { name: 'Plumber' },
          relations: { relatedTo: true },
        }
// ==> plumber.relatedTo will be empty

Is there a way to solve this without resorting to a making raw query with a union, or with a simple work around?
Thanks
